# API and Documentation

Tags: nest-api

I just enrolled as a nest developer and have been reading through the API and Documentation.  I have seen the endpoint's and process required to sign in, however I've been unable to find what end points are required to access data on the various devices?  Most of the API and Documentation seems to focus on Firebase.

Searching for the answer shows a lot of older (2 years) projects that are probably out of date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The endpoint begins at `https://developer-api.nest.com/`

Data is accessed at a path after that url. So, if you just want devices, your endpoint is `https://developer-api.nest.com/devices`

Just thermostats? `https://developer-api.nest.com/devices/thermostats`

And so on. If you look at the reference api, you can see the paths